# Can not get two day name after joining two table using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue. I am joining two table and can not get the proper data using MySQL.I am explaining my table below.

> db_day:

```
day_id        day_name

  1            Monday

  2            Tuesday

  3            Wednesday

  4            Thursday

  5            Friday

  6            Saturday

  7            Sunday
```

> db_images:

```
id    name    from_day    to_day

 1     Raj       1          3

 2     Rahul     4          7
```

I am explaining my query below.

```
select sl.id,sl.name,sl.from_day,sl.to_day,d.day_name,d.day_id from db_images as sl left join db_day as d on d.day_id=sl.from_day sl.id desc
```

Here i need both `from day and to day` with the name after joining the table but here i am getting the `from day` only .Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Join the `db_day` table twice with different alias names

```
select sl.id, sl.name, sl.from_day, sl.to_day,
       d1.day_name as from_day, d1.day_id as from_id,
       d2.day_name as to_day, d2.day_id as to_id 
from db_images sl 
left join db_day d1 on d1.day_id = sl.from_day
left join db_day d2 on d2.day_id = sl.to_day
```

Comment: @ juergen d,   what about if we use `subquery` here? will it be slower then `join`?

Comment: Subqueries are mostly slower.

Comment: `from_id` and `to_id` are same i think.

Comment: They are not. They are equal to `sl.from_day` and `sl.to_day`.